# Correct way to dump a packet

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to build a sniffer to sniff TCP Headers and i got myself thinking...Doing raw_socket.close() is the correct way to dump a packet that didn't came from port 80? I feel like there could be a more pythonic way to do it without having to close a connection and create another, hence my doubt. This is my code which probably need some improvements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time,socket,struct

while True:
    raw_socket = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(0x0800))

    packet=raw_socket.recv(2048)

    tcp_hdr=packet[34:54]

    print("\nTCP Header: %s"%tcp_hdr)

    unpacked=struct.unpack("!HHLLBBHHH",tcp_hdr)

    if unpacked[0] != 80:
        print("Not port 80...Dumping packet...")
        raw_socket.close()
    else:

        #TCP Header Fields

        src_port=unpacked[0]
        dest_port=unpacked[1]
        seq_number=unpacked[2]
        ack_number=unpacked[3]
        data_offset=unpacked[4]
        reserved=unpacked[5]
        flags=unpacked[6]
        window=unpacked[7]
        checksum=unpacked[8]

        print("\n\t\tFields\n")
        print("Source Port: %d\nDestination Port: %d"%(src_port,dest_port))
        print("Sequence Number: %d\nAcknowledgement Number: %d"%(seq_number,ack_number))
        print("Data Offset: %d\nReserved: %d"%(data_offset,reserved))
        print("Flags: %d"%flags)
        print("Checksum: %d"%checksum)

        raw_socket.close()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: The packet is "dumped" from the network stack when you recv it. You don't have to do anything special. Move the socket creation out of the loop and get rid of the `close` calls.

Comment: Closing the socket does dump packets in the queue that you haven't received yet. So, for instance, when you get a port 80 hit and wait 5 seconds, the close/open sequence will get you the latest packets. If that's what you want, then yeah, you have to close. I would (1) not close on rejected packets and (2) close early on the port 80 packets (close, process, open).

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney. If you can create an answer i will accept it